# Change "add to cart" text for not registered users

Tags: magento2, addtocart

What the best way to change text `add to cart` only for not registered users?

1. Documentation recommend change dictionary file. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html but this solution works for all users
2. Create some `plugin/observer` for `Magento\Framework\Phrase\Renderer\Translate.`

Answer (score 1):

You have to override js file from path and all user for translate text this file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

To

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Packadge/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

You have to changes text which you want to from this file.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this, but I would recommend it by overriding the template file.

To do so, just copy the file **`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`** and put it under **`app/design/frontend/{theme-package}/{theme}/Magento/Catalog/templates/product`** folder.

Now you can programmatically check whether a customer is logged into the website or not, and based on that you can change the value of **__('Add to Cart')** to whatever you want.

Since the solution needs some custom code, it is not possible by simply writing the translation in the translation files.

The above solution is the simplest one and it also does not break any Magento standard.

Comment: this might not work with FPC enabled

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution to change the "Add to cart" only for **not registred** users is to do something like this:

Not registred means not logged in

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}{themename}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>

/* ***** We do our stuff right here ***** */
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart');
} else {
    $buttonTitle = __('Text for not registred user');
}

...
```

In the case you want to get the registred users:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$website_id = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$customer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId($website_id);
$customer->load('CUSTOMER_ID');

if ( $customer->getId() ) {
      // the customer exist
} else {
      // does't exist
}
```